# iPhone RSA text encoding + decoding

Tags: iphone, encoding, rsa, decoding

What should happen.

User send encrypted message to the server. Other user retrieve message from the the server and then decript it. And vice versa.

I have some text in unicode encoding. Text should send to the server using RSA encription as a part of `JSON` (like  {"message" : ""}  )

To encript text I create function that have `NSString` as an input parametr and `NSString` as an output parametr. Decript function have the same format.

**My problem**: text that is a result of decode function not the same that was encoded.

```
-(NSString*) encryptText:(NSString*) text {

OSStatus status = noErr;

//text = @"ネイティブ英会話";
text = @"test text";

int length = [text lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
const char *cText = [text cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

size_t cipherBufferSize = BUFFER_SIZE;
if (cipherBufferSize < length) {
    cipherBufferSize = length;
}

char *cipherBuffer = malloc(cipherBufferSize);
memset(cipherBuffer, 0, cipherBufferSize);

NSLog(@"BEFORE SIPHER TEXT = %s", cText);

status = SecKeyEncrypt(_publicKey,
                       kSecPaddingNone,
                       (unsigned char*) cText,
                       length,
                       (unsigned char*) cipherBuffer,
                       &cipherBufferSize
                       );

NSLog(@"CIPHER TEXT = %s", cipherBuffer);

NSString *result = nil;

if (status == 0) {
    result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", cipherBuffer];
}

free(cipherBuffer);

return result;
}


-(NSString*) decriptText:(NSString*) encriptedText {

OSStatus status = noErr;

const char *cText = [encriptedText cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

int length = [encriptedText lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

size_t plainBufferSize = BUFFER_SIZE;
if (plainBufferSize < length) {
    plainBufferSize = length;
}

char *plainBuffer = malloc(plainBufferSize);
memset(plainBuffer, 0, plainBufferSize);

NSLog(@"BEFORE DECIPHER TEXT = %s", cText);

status = SecKeyDecrypt(_privateKey,
                       kSecPaddingNone,
                       (unsigned char *) cText,
                       length,
                       (unsigned char *) plainBuffer,
                       &plainBufferSize
                       );

NSLog(@"AFTER DESIPHER BUFFER = %s status = %d", plainBuffer, status);

NSString *decriptedText = nil;

if (status == 0) {
    decriptedText = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:plainBuffer]; 
}

free(plainBuffer);

return decriptedText;
 }
```

Comment: were you able to resolve your problem ? If yes can you please post solution for encryption and decryption both function. I am getting weird characters in encrypted string while encrypting. Any idea ?

Comment: I don't solve this problem. But I think it can be useful now.
[link](https://github.com/search?q=rsa&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Everything&language=Objective-C)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050158/iphone-rsa-text-encoding-decoding